# extending a harmonic function and finding a non-trivial example

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-functions, reflection

Suppose $u$ is a harmonic function on $\Delta(0,1)$ which extends continuously to $\{x^2+y^2\leq 1: x>0\}$ and is constant on $\{x^2+y^2=1| x>0\}$. Show that $u$ extends to a function whch is harmonic in a neighbourhood of $(1,0)$. What is the largest open set to which $u$ extends as a harmonic function? Can you give a non trivial example of such a function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "Schwarz reflection principle"?

Comment: Yes. So that tells me $u$ is harmonic on all of $\Delta(0,1)$. What about outside the disc?
Also, what is the significance of it being constant on the boundary of the upper half plane? 
So, we'll get $f$ is analytic and constant on boundary and we can proceed from there?

Comment: $u$ is the real part of a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Delta(0, 1)$. $f$ is constant on $\{x^2+y^2=1| x>0\}$, so you can apply the reflection principle to $f$ and continue it analytically to a larger domain.

Comment: But to apply the reflection principle, don't I need $u$ to be zero (or at least real maybe) on the real axis?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Riemann Mapping Theorem we take the unit disc to the upper half plane and map the right boundary of the disc to the interval $(-1,1)$ on the real axis. We can apply the Schwarz Reflection Principle and extend the harmonic function harmonically to the entire strip $\{z=x+iy | |x|<1\}$. By defining $u(\bar{z})=u(z)$ we can in fact extend it to the entire complex plane except the part of the real axis where $|x|>1$.

A possible non-trivial example can be $u(z)=\Re(\sqrt{z^2-1})$ where we choose the branch cuts accordingly.

Comment: You certainly don't need the RMT for this.

Comment: I find it easier to work with the upper half plane, and at least for the example I wanted to construct it was easier for me to see in the upper half plane rather than the unit disc itself!